# Postgres replication: Do I need to rsync pg_xlog files if I have archiving setup in master?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am trying to replicate a master to slave, without shutting down my master.

In the tutorial here: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Binary_Replication_Tutorial, they recommend these steps:

1. pg_start_backup()
2. rsync -av --exclude pg_xlog --exclude postgresql.conf --exclude postgresql.pid \ 
    data/*  :/var/lib/postgresql/data/
3. pg_stop_backup()
4. rsync -av data/pg_xlog :/var/lib/postgresql/data/

Steps 1-3 are straightforward. However, If I setup archiving in the master and archiving in my slave, do I need to execute step 4? Will it mess things up? Should I NOT setup archiving until everything is rsync'd and my slave is running?

My master's config file looks like this:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p <INSERT SLAVE IP>:/var/lib/pgsql/data/archive/%f'
```

Likewise, my slave has a recovery.conf with a restore_command.

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial appears to be old, and also says "work in progress" at the top. I'll amend it if I have time. Please refer to [the main documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html).

If you have continuous archiving set up you don't need to manually rsync the WAL, because your `archive_command` will do that for you.

You may also wish to consider [using `pg_basebackup`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgbasebackup.html) instead of manually rsync'ing the datadir. It'll take care of everything for you over the PostgreSQL replication protocol. If you weren't using WAL archiving you'd use `-X stream` mode to get it to copy the WAL for you too, but you don't need that.

Comment: If you have archiving setup, is it technically possible for the rsync for the initial data files to take a very very long time, and still have replication succeed if you have a very busy database?

Comment: @HenleyChiu Yes, because the replica will catch up to the master using archives and begin streaming once it's caught up. As always, test.